# Flows - How to skip the record that initiate the flow from the Get records?

Tags: visual-workflow

I am facing a situation like this. I am creating a New record in a custom object. Email Id is a field of that. While creating this I need to check if the there is already an existing record in that object with same email id, if so I need to check the checkbox. I need to implement it using a flow. The issue in the get records, flow is fetching my present record and since email id is already there, it checks the check box. I need to avoid the new record i am inputting and search only all other records in the system. I tried by using id doesnot equal {!$Record.Id}. But it is still fetching the record and always checking the checkbox

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In flow, I have used 'Get record' gets all the records of a custom object say obj1 . Is there a way to skip the current record of obj1 that triggered the flow and read all other records of obj1?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit of an "[xy](https://xyproblem.info/)" problem.

That aside, it sounds like what you really want is to set a checkbox field if the email ID already exists for another record.

You don't need to query all records. Simply run a query in your flow to check for existing records with the same Email ID value as $Record. Later in your flow, you check the size of that GET element. If it is greater than zero, that means you have a match. And you can set the checkbox field to true.

Your flow will look something like this (screenshot):
[image]